# Duplicate file processing by FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter with MongoDB Metadatastore

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Two instances of our spring integration application deployed on host1 and host2 are processing incoming files on a shared mount point /opt/tomcat/in 
Sometimes both applications are processing the same file causing duplicate file processing.

We are using ChainFileListFilter as:

```
public ChainFileListFilter getFilters(String pattern){
    ChainFileListFilter chainFileListFilter = new ChainFileListFilter();
    chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new LastModifiedFileListFilter());
    chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
    chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(mongoMetadataStore(), ""));
    return chainFileListFilter;
}
```

From the MongoDB collection, we see there is only one entry for the file.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "/opt/tomcat/in/850/order_12345_2019-03-25_09-00-52.xml",
    "value" : "1553522452000"
}
```

However as seen from the server logs, both applications processed the same file with an interval of few seconds.

```
[user@host1.prod.env (prod) logs]$ 
server.log:2019-03-25 **09:30:14.943** INFO  [task-scheduler-4] o.s.i.f.FileReadingMessageSource [FileReadingMessageSource.java:380] Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=/opt/tomcat/in/850/order_12345_2019-03-25_09-00-52.xml, headers={id=2dee86bb-701a-6f55-3e58-6ea3d78cdc30, timestamp=1553524214943}]]


[user@host2.prod.env (prod) logs]$
server.log:2019-03-25 **09:30:16.680** INFO  [task-scheduler-4] o.s.i.f.FileReadingMessageSource [FileReadingMessageSource.java:380] Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=/opt/tomcat/in/850/order_12345_2019-03-25_09-00-52.xml, headers={id=3bc4b67c-a9d0-9f1a-667f-5aaa50c88a1a, timestamp=1553524216680}]]
```

Application is build with Spring Boot Version = '1.5.4.RELEASE'

With few files we don't see duplicate file processing issue, however, with few hundred (100,200) files we are seeing duplicate file processing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you have an issue that file has been modified in between those polls.

The `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` works the way that it checks a `File.lastModified()` and replace an entry in the store if an old value is different.

You may consider also add a `LastModifiedFileListFilter` to the chain before `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`. So, you won't poll the file until is old enough according its `lastModified()`.

Comment: filter is not picking up files